# Pfister shower handle

Tags: shower, leak

I have the same problem as several others.
It is always best to Start from the beginning. The shower head was leaking: I replaced the valve stem assy, essy-peasy, installed the same as the old one. The handle travels appx. 150 degrees counter clockwise. I have read the forums such as this one. At one point I was getting reversed hot & cold water. I read where I should turn the valve stem 180 degrees, this did not work either It reversed the direction the handle travels. I got a cartridge 974-042 that was no better. Today reinstalled new oem parts as originally installed and no hot water.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate cartridge, not the valve stem

Comment: If I rotate the cartridge the valve stem rotates also, it is all one piece, it can only work  2 ways , either one is just 180 degrees from the other. I wish I could post pic's. maybe I can, just don't know how

Comment: Does it change the hot / cold though? If so, your original question is addressed. Then to deal with the handle. Can you just undo the handle reattach 180?

Comment: Oh answer to your question yes I do get hot and cold the clod comes out  when the hot is suppose to  and vice versa I posted this question to Pfister, they refered me to a YouTube video, it is so simple 5 screws including the one that tightens the handle, if I follow their video and I have. The handle is on the wrong side and I get only cold water. The water mixer is part of the handle stem

Comment: @wilbo9619 post that (and a link to the video) as an answer to help others.